# the meaning of real in Garbage Collection logs?how can i minimize it

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

what's the meaning of real?
The user and system only cost a little time,why it's cost so many time?
To minimize the Garbage Collection times,what can I do?
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4n2Z.png

Comment: there are whole books around garbage collection, how to minimize full GCs, what's happening, etc., do a little searching because it's a subject area rife with data and information

Comment: As a general rule, please don't post screenshots of code.  SO has lovely code markup just for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DefNew

That's the single-threaded collector. Choose a different one.

Read [oracle's GC tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/) for alternatives.